# Matplotlib not resizing plots inside figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

[image]This is a live animation plotting streaming data. My backend is GTKAgg. My matplotlib version is `1.2.0`.

In the constructor of my class, I do

```
self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 10)) # gets called once
```

Then, the run method, called repeatedly, looks like this

```
  def run(self):
        # called repeatedly
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure,
                                           partial(self.gen_data, self.data_for_symbol))
        print 'Figure ', self.figure, matplotlib.get_backend()
        plt.ion()
        plt.draw()
        plt.tight_layout()
        self.figure.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

Then I use the mouse to drag the edges of the figure to resize it, but it ens up looking like in the attached picture(note the wide grey area). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of the issue?! Does it depend on whether you use `plt.ion` and `FuncAnimation` (which may not make too much sense in combination anyways)? Why are you repeatedly creating a new animation? Why are you repeatedly calling `show`? Also mind that version 1.2 is already a couple of years old, so if this is an issue with this old version, it's unlikely that someone can still reproduce it.

Comment: Unfortunately my code is not clean enough to be able to extract a minimal example. I am using plt.ion() because otherwise my code was blocking there. I am not experienced with these tools, so if you can suggest an alternative to do this in a more practical, straightforward way, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: The problem is that if I execute the self.ani=... it does not call the self.gen_data method, i.e. the animation does not update at all